# Does graphql support filters on aggregates?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I would like to know if graphql can be used to construct queries that use aggregate filters. Something like `having max(customers) < 10`

As an example (please the filter criteria where I would like to specify count as one of the criteria) :

```
query {
  allMovies {
    title
    _actorsMeta {
      count
    }
  }
  _allMoviesMeta(filter: {
    title_starts_with: "Inception"
    ***count : > 5***
  }) {
    count
  }
}
```

Comment: what are you using for the graphql server? is it a third party api?

Comment: I intend to use Apollo client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GraphQL doesn’t support this **on the spec level**. And there is a good reason why. If GraphQL specification supported filter and aggregates it would obligate all the users to implement this functionality and this may be very inefficient or just not needed for some domains/use cases. Why do I have implement/support aggregates if my users do not need them?

But GraphQL gives you flexibility, so you can always implement filtering/aggregates for your fields via parameters. Taking your example it may look like bellow:

```
query {
  allMovies {
    title
    _actorsMeta {
      count
    }
  }
  _allMoviesMeta(filter: {
    title: {startsWith: “Inception”},
    count: { gt: 5 }
  }) {
    count
  }
}
```

But you’ll have to implement all the filtering logic on your back end. The good explanation is posted by @batjko in the comment to [the similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35036221/support-of-aggregate-function-in-graphql?rq=1#comment60802631_35074801):

> Every GraphQL query is responded to by a resolve() function. The query
>   parameters you give to the query are the arguments to this function.
>   The resolve() function then goes away and does anything you want, say
>   retrieve the results of a SQL query from elsewhere, then you can
>   aggregate that data as you like, and finally return the outcome of all
>   that as your response to the GraphQL query.

In case you don’t control the backend you can do filtering/aggregation on the front end.
I’m one of the authors of [graphql-lodash](https://github.com/apis-guru/graphql-lodash) which gives you a declarative way to specify result transformations.
You query may look like:

```
query {
  allMovies {
    title
    _actorsMeta {
      count
    }
  }
  _allMoviesMeta @_(
    rejectIf: { 
      and: [
        { get: “сount”, gt: 5 }
        { get: “title”, startsWith: “Inception” }
      ]
    }
  ) {
    title
    count
  }
}
```

If you use Appollo Client, check the article on how to use it together: [Query and transformation collocation in Apollo Client](https://blog.apis.guru/query-and-transformation-collocation-with-apollo-client-and-graphql-lodash-9111448ec01b). [React](https://github.com/APIs-guru/react-apollo-lodash-demo) and [Angular](https://github.com/APIs-guru/angular-apollo-lodash-demo) examples are included .

Also, you are welcome to provide your feedback or suggestions - just open an issue in our [GitHub repository](https://github.com/APIs-guru/graphql-lodash).