# Aggregate function returns null GraphQL

Tags: node.js, express, graphql

I am testing a basic aggregation function using counts from Sequelize and here's my type **Counts**:

```
type Creserve {
    id: ID!
    rDateStart: Date!
    rDateEnd: Date!
    grade: Int!
    section: String!
    currentStatus: String!
    user: User! 
    cartlab: Cartlab! 
}
type Counts {
    section: String!
    count: Int
}
type Query {
    getBooking(id: ID!): Creserve!
    allBookings: [Creserve]
    getBookingByUser(userId: ID): Creserve
    upcomingBookings: [Creserve]  
    countBookings: [Counts]
}
```

I am using countBookings as my query for aggregate functions and here's my resolver for the query:

```
countBookings: async (parent, args, {models}) => 
    {
      const res = await models.Creserve.findAndCountAll({
        group: 'section',
        attributes: ['section', [Sequelize.fn('COUNT', 'section'), 'count']]
      });
        return res.rows;
  },
```

The query that it outputs is this:

```
Executing (default): SELECT "section", COUNT('section') AS "count" FROM "Creserve" AS "Creserve" GROUP BY "section";
```

And tried this query in my psql shell and it's working fine:

```
 section | count
---------+-------
 A       |     2
 R       |     2
```

However, when I tried querying **countBookings** in my GraphQL Playground, section is returned but not the count:

```
    {
  "data": {
    "countBookings": [
      {
        "section": "A",
        "count": null
      },
      {
        "section": "R",
        "count": null
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Is there something I missed out? Or is this a bug? This is the answer I tried following to with this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45586121/9760036

Thank you very much!

edit: returning a console.log(res.rows) outputs something like this:

```
   [ Creserve {
    dataValues: { section: 'A', count: '2' },
    _previousDataValues: { section: 'A', count: '2' },
    _changed: {},
    _modelOptions:
     { timestamps: true,
       validate: {},
       freezeTableName: true,
       underscored: false,
       underscoredAll: false,
       paranoid: false,
       rejectOnEmpty: false,
       whereCollection: null,
       schema: null,
       schemaDelimiter: '',
       defaultScope: {},
       scopes: [],
       indexes: [],
       name: [Object],
       omitNull: false,
       hooks: [Object],
       sequelize: [Sequelize],
       uniqueKeys: {} },
    _options:
     { isNewRecord: false,
       _schema: null,
       _schemaDelimiter: '',
       raw: true,
       attributes: [Array] },
    __eagerlyLoadedAssociations: [],
    isNewRecord: false },
  Creserve {
    dataValues: { section: 'R', count: '2' },
    _previousDataValues: { section: 'R', count: '2' },
    _changed: {},
    _modelOptions:
     { timestamps: true,
       validate: {},
       freezeTableName: true,
       underscored: false,
       underscoredAll: false,
       paranoid: false,
       rejectOnEmpty: false,
       whereCollection: null,
       schema: null,
       schemaDelimiter: '',
       defaultScope: {},
       scopes: [],
       indexes: [],
       name: [Object],
       omitNull: false,
       hooks: [Object],
       sequelize: [Sequelize],
       uniqueKeys: {} },
    _options:
     { isNewRecord: false,
       _schema: null,
       _schemaDelimiter: '',
       raw: true,
       attributes: [Array] },
    __eagerlyLoadedAssociations: [],
    isNewRecord: false } ]
```

Here's for res.count:

```
Executing (default): SELECT "section", COUNT('section') AS "count" FROM "Creserve" AS "Creserve" GROUP BY "section";
[ { count: '2' }, { count: '2' } ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**

Actually you are doing everything right here... but what is happening here is the `sequlize` doesn't return plain object... It always returns the data in form of `instance` like that

```
[ Creserve {
    dataValues: { section: 'A', count: '2' },
    _previousDataValues: { section: 'A', count: '2' },
    _changed: {},
    _modelOptions:
     { timestamps: true,
```

**Solution**

> I am not sure but there is no other way instead of looping and makes
>   response to json object...

```
const array = []
res.rows.map((data) => {
  array.push(data.toJSON())
})
return array
```

Comment: I added console.log for res.rows and res.count and it seems to output as to how to wanted me to change it. How do you return both? Sorry I am just new to javascript I am still currently learning.

And both counts are returning a string, not an integer.

Comment: There. Completed the response. The fields in res.rows are inside the DataValues.

Comment: Here's the output:

Executing (default): SELECT "section", COUNT('section') AS "count" FROM "Creserve" AS "Creserve" GROUP BY "section";

{ section: 'A', count: '2' }

Comment: Hey I tried it and playground read the response. Is there a way to append objects in an array from that response? Or convert it to an array?

```      const array = [{ section: "A", count: 2 }, { section: "R", count: 2 }];
```

response:
 "data": {
    "countBookings": [
      {
        "section": "A",
        "count": "2"
      },
      {
        "section": "R",
        "count": "2"
      }
    ]
  }
}

Comment: Yes that response came from the GraphQL Playground so it did read the array you gave.

And I found out that doing a findAndCountAll then doing a function count in the attributes is already redundant that's why it does a count in both res.rows and res.count.

Comment: `{ 
      const array = [];
       const res = await models.Creserve.findAndCountAll({
        group: 'section',
        attributes: ['section', [Sequelize.fn('COUNT', 'section'), 'count']]
      }).then(response => {
        return array.push(response.rows[0].toJSON());
      })
    }`

So i tested how to make the response into an array and I know it's a bit messy of a code but I'll just make a forEach later but yeah I guess. Thanks. Do you have any suggestions on how to make this more efficient?

Comment: Cool that's better than the for loop I currently do now. Thanks a lot